# How to redirect the user to a specific route after login/register?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-6

I have multi language application, so when the user logs in or register they need to be redirect to their home of the specific language. In my case `en/home` or `pt/home`.

I already tried to overwrite the `$redirectTo` property in the `Login/Register Controllers`, but it does not work.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return  app()->getLocale().'/home';
}
```

Also tried to use the`authenticated` method:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect(app()->getLocale() .'/home');
}
```

Why this methods are not working? I looked most of the questions about this here in SO but none of the answers worked so far.

Comment: The `RegisterController` sets the page to redirect to after a user has been registered. You'd need the `LoginController` (as far as I can recall, that was its proper name) to set the page to redirect to after login.

Comment: Already did that, i used the redirectTo method in both controllers (RegisterController and LoginController).

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Also, make sure you got your locale set when the user logs in. You might also want to investigate which methods from the underlying controllers utilize the `$redirectTo` attribute and look up what's going on.

Comment: Im using laravel 6 and locale is set in both routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a problem on the `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` file. I had to change the handle function to:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect()->route('home', app()->getLocale());
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

When a user closes the browser without loging out and then try to access the page again in a short period of time (before the login token expires) this is function is called instead of the `redirectTo()` method in the `LoginController`. So the problem was only  happening in this specific case.